# Regex - Delete everything before first match

Tags: regex

Really struggling with this one. I need a regular expression to remove the subject/to/from/date fields from an e-mail, but leaving all previous subject/to/from/date field entries within the mail chain. For example:

```
Subject: RE: Test mail
From: test@stackoverflow.com
To: test@test.com
Date: 22/06/2018 10:00:00

This is the body of e-mail #3.

Subject: RE: Test mail
From: test@test.com
To: test@stackoverflow.com
Date: 22/06/2018 09:55:00

This is the body of e-mail #2.

Subject: Test mail
From: test@stackoverflow.com
To: test@test.com
Date: 22/06/2018 09:50:00

This is the body of e-mail #1.
```

I'd like the regular expression to remove simply the top five lines to give:

```
This is the body of e-mail #3.

Subject: RE: Test mail
From: test@test.com
To: test@stackoverflow.com
Date: 22/06/2018 09:55:00

This is the body of e-mail #2.

Subject: Test mail
From: test@stackoverflow.com
To: test@test.com
Date: 22/06/2018 09:50:00

This is the body of e-mail #1.
```

Unfortunately, I can't write anything that specifically deletes the first five lines as there may also be a CC field; which means it could potentially be six lines.

It therefore needs to match the first instance of "Date:" until the end of the line and delete everything before. Any ideas would be hugely appreciated; the closest I've got is the below which unfortunately matches both instances of "Date:".

```
[\s\S]*.*Date:.*[\s\S]
```

Comment: in which language you try this and which code apply for this share ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the first part of the text until `Date:` and also select that line you might use:

[`^Subject:[\s\S]+?^Date:[^\r\n]+\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/2yxQV4/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` From the start of the line
- `Subject:` Match literally
- `[\s\S]+?` Match a whitespace character or a non whitespace character one or more times non greedy
- `^Date:` Match the start of the line followed by `Date:`
- `[^\r\n]+` Match not a carriage return of a newline character one or more times
- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character

Note that in the example the global flag is off to select only a single match.

An alternative to using `[\s\S]+?` might be to use a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?s)` to let the dot match all characters including line breaks.

`(?s)^Subject:.+?^Date:[^\r\n]+\s*`

Then you could for example replace the match with an empty string or capture the rest that follows in a (the first) capturing group:

[`^Subject:[\s\S]+?^Date:[^\r\n]+\s*([\s\S]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/2XtGjb/2) (If you use pcre, instead of a capturing group you could use [`\K[\s\S]+`](https://regex101.com/r/2XtGjb/1))

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be constructed the following way:

- Start from the start of string.
- Accept any content up to a line starting from "Date: ".
- Accept the rest of this line.
- Accept any number of following `\n` chars (the end of this line and following empty lines).

No `g` (global) option, since you want to perform only a **single** match.

So one of possible solutions can be as follows:

```
/\A.+?^Date: [^\n]+\n+/ms
```

Details:

- `m` option - multi-line (`^` and `$` match also start / end of line).
- `s` option - single-line (`.` matches also `\n`).
- `\A` - Start of the whole string.
- `.+?` - Any number of any chars (due to `s` option, including `\n`).
- `^` - Start of a line (due to `m` option).
- `Date:` - Start of the "Date" line.
- `[^\n]+` - Any number of chars other than `\n` - the actual date field.
- `\n+` - The end of line and following empty lines.

As you specified neither the host language nor regex version,
I assumed PCRE, supporting all the features used.

Answer (score 0):

`^.*?\n\n(.*)` with options (gms) will capture the desired output in group 1.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/rlWxoW/1)

Alternatively, `^.*?\n\n` with options (ms) will match only the text to remove.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/rlWxoW/2)

Both of these regular expressions rely on matching the first empty line. This means that even if there is an extra field (e.g. a CC field) this method will still work.